# take screenshot from ACTION_DIAL intent -java android

Tags: android

i am amateur in android 
i want to take a screenshot from dial activity of user`s phone,
i use this for going to dial page

```
 Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
          startActivity(call);
```

what is the best way for get screenshot without root? and we should write the code inside onPause() method? because our app is paused when we go to an intent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library for getting screen shot

[Link](https://github.com/tarek360/InstaCapture)

hope it help